# How to resize image of checkbox in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, checkbox

I am adding image for a CheckBox widget (that is instead of the default one for both clicked and unclicked ones in .xml file using selector) it's getting added, but the image can't be resized into a smaller one and remains in its original size.

**How could I decrease the image size?**

The code I used to create the CheckBox is

```
    <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:button="@drawable/check_box"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:text="check box text"
            android:textColor="@color/labelColor" />
```

Answer (score 12):

Set the `android:button` field to **null** and to set the checkbox as the `android:background` field of the checkbox

```
    <CheckBox    
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:text="check box text"
            android:background="@drawable/check_box" />
```

Comment: isnt this helpfull ? @allDroid

Comment: worked for me @Amit Vaghela Thanks 
The icon was appearing only partially, with this change icon size is reduced accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

To set the **android:button** field to null and to set the checkbox states as the **android:background** field of the checkbox.

Your code would then become:

```
<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/cb"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:button="@null"
android:background="@drawable/check_box"
android:drawablePadding="20dp"
android:text="check box text"
android:textColor="@color/labelColor" />
```

Answer (score 0):

@berry: Please set  `android:button="@null"` and set this in your `android:background` .

```
 android:button="@null"
 android:background="@drawable/check_box"
```

CheckBox doesn't respect the size of the ***android:button drawable when the layout width and height are set to wrap_content***. So use **android:background** .